# how to convert string to byte in java?

Tags: java, string, binary, byte

How to make string "01001000"(for example) to byte and convert it to string.

Example :

if string = "0110000101100010" then output must be "ab"

because a == 01100001 and b == 01100010

Comment: www.google.com/search?q=binary+string+to+byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this:

```
      String[] array = {"01100001","01100010"};
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for( String string : array ) {
          sb.append( (char)Integer.parseInt( string, 2 ) );
      }
```

or if you have one String which has exact 8-bit * x letter.

```
    String source = "0110000101100010";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i = 0; i < source.length(); i= i+8 ) {
        sb.append( (char)Integer.parseInt( source.substring( i, i+8 ), 2 ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String str : "0110000101100010".split("(?<=\\G.{8})")){
    sb.append((char)Byte.parseByte(str,2));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Will output --> ab